# Powershell capture a text pattern in files and replace characters in the pattern

Tags: regex, powershell

**What I have is:**

I have made a simple Powershell script to replace the contents of the text files and rewrite the files (UTF8 encoding is crucial):

`((Get-Content -path *.adoc -Raw -Encoding utf8) -replace '\[.dfn .term]#.*#','[.dfn .term]_.*_') | Set-Content -Path *.adoc -Encoding utf8`

When I tried to run the script like this, I found out that I'm replacing a regex string with a plain text string.

**What I want to achieve is:**

Find a line that begins with `[.dfn .term]`, has any number of characters between `#` and `#`, and replace `#` with `_`. Leaving `[.dfn .term]` and `# everything between #` unchanged.

I can't replace all `#` with `_` because there can also be text like `[.keyword]#something#` and it will need replacing `#` with `*`. Also, `something` can be anything - a word or a phrase.

Dealing with patterns and RegEx groups is outside my knowledge. I would appreciate any help.

**Example:**

**I have:** A sentence is a string of `[.dfn .term]#Words#` that has a finished `[.keyword]#Thought#`. Sentences form `[.dfn .term]#Paragraphs#`. `[.dfn .term]#Paragraphs#` form text. Text is cool.

**I want to have:** A sentence is a string of `[.dfn .term]_Words_` that has a finished `[.keyword]*Thought*`. Sentences form `[.dfn .term]_Paragraphs_`. `[.dfn .term]_Paragraphs_` form text. Text is cool.

Comment: Could you post some examples of the value you could have and the expected value after replacing, I think it will be easier to understand and help you.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use these regex with groups to help you:

```
$lines = Get-Content -Path C:\file.txt -Encoding UTF8 -Raw
$option = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline 

$pattern1 = [regex]::new("(\[\.dfn \.term])#(.*?)#", $option)
#be careful simple quote is important here
$lines = $pattern1.Replace($lines, '$1_$2_')

$pattern2 = [regex]::new("(\[what you want])#(.*?)#", $option)
$lines = $pattern2.Replace($lines, '$1*$2*')

$lines | Set-Content -Path C:\result.txt -Encoding UTF8
```

test file:

```
[.dfn .term]#azaeaeae#

[.dfn .term]#errrr# sqsqsqs


[.dfn .term]#errrr# sqsqsqs
eaeaeaeae
aeaeae
[.dfn .term]#errrr# [.keyword]#something# #errrr#
```

result: (with second pattern .keyword)

```
[.dfn .term]_azaeaeae_


[.dfn .term]_errrr_ sqsqsqs


[.dfn .term]_errrr_ sqsqsqs
eaeaeaeae
aeaeae
[.dfn .term]_errrr_ [.keyword]*something* #errrr#
```

you could write too:

```
$lines = (Get-Content -path C:\yourfile.txt -Raw -Encoding utf8) `
                -replace '(\[\.dfn \.term])#(.*?)#', '$1_$2_' `
                -replace '(\[\.keyword])#(.*?)#', '$1*$2*'
```

you could use named groups if you want:

```
$pattern1 = [regex]::new("(?<begin>\[\.dfn \.term])#(?<text>.*?)#", $option)
#be careful simple quote is important here
$lines = $pattern1.Replace($lines, '${begin}_${text}_')
```

if you have lot of patterns different, you could put them in an object:

```
$patterns = @{
 '(\[\.dfn \.term])#(.*?)#' = '$1_$2_' ;
 '(\[\.keyword])#(.*?)#' = '$1*$2*'
}
$option = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline 

foreach($k in $patterns.Keys){
  $pat = [regex]::new($k, $option)
  $lines = $pat.Replace($lines, $patterns.$k)
}
```

Comment: The script is not replacing for some reason. It runs without returning any errors, but no changes are being made to the file.

Comment: so you have a problem pattern/ what you have exactly in your file.. are you sure space is not tab..or other problem.. i have no problem with a test file..could you post a part of your test file?

Comment: dont forget to escape some character which are specials `([.`  for example

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I copied the script entirely to test it. I put a new file to the root of the disk. The file contains 5 lines - 3 have `[.dfn .term]#Word#` plus 2 blank lines. The only thing I changed in the script was the path to the file from C: to D:. Is there a need for Set-Content to write the file?

Comment: i save the file with Set-content but the result is already in the variable..

Comment: are you sure to use simple quote for the replacement part?

Comment: Just the same as in your answer: `$pattern1 = [regex]::new("(\[\.dfn \.term])#(.*?)#", $option)` - double quotes `"`, `$lines = $pattern1.Replace($lines, '$1_$2_')` - single quotes `'`.

Comment: its a mysterious problem..... could you test `$result = (Get-Content -path C:\yourfile.txt -Raw -Encoding utf8) -replace '(\[\.dfn \.term])#(.*?)#', '$1_$2_'`  its another way to write the code with same regex

Comment: Tried with `$lines | Set-Content -Path C:\result.txt -Encoding UTF8` and the result.txt is created. But it does not want to alter the file.txt and it will not overwrite it if I explicitly say `$lines | Set-Content -Path C:\file.txt -Encoding UTF8`.

Comment: may, you havent the permission to write on c:\?  readonly or other? filebusy?

Comment: I am testing with all paths replaced by D:\ and result.txt is created at D:\ so I do have permission. I replaced `$lines = $pattern1.Replace($lines, '$1_$2_')` with `$result = (Get-Content -path C:\yourfile.txt -Raw -Encoding utf8) -replace '(\[\.dfn \.term])#(.*?)#', '$1_$2_'` and have the same result - no overwrite.

Comment: With `$lines | Set-Content -Path D:\result.txt -Encoding UTF8 ` it actually even overwrites `D:\result.txt ` if I alter it manually and then just run the script once again. Very strange. I will mark your answer as solved and post another question about my powershell problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a regexp that matches JUST the # symbols following the [.dfn .term] and at the end of the line.

Here's an example:

```
"[.dfn .term]# everything between #" -replace "(?<=\[\.dfn \.term\])#|#$", "_"
```

...which results in: [.dfn .term]_ everything between _

Here's how it breaks down:

(?<=[.dfn .term]) - looks for [.dfn .term], but does not match the text. It's called a positive look behind.

# - matches the pound sign

| - OR

#$ - matches the pound sign at the end of the line

Comment: You say `#$ - matches the pound sign at the end of the line`. What if what I search is not at the end of the **line**, but in a paragraph or anywhere else? And will UTF8 encoding be preserved?

Comment: Also, will I be able to substitute `everything between` with regex since it can be different from one instance to another?

Comment: Given your new example, you can use: (?<=\[.*\])\#|(?<=\[.*\]\#.*?)(?<!\#)\#